# C# methods, using refs and outs to modify variables

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out how to use separate methods to modify variables. The code I'm posting is what I'm working on, and while I know there are much better and easier ways of doing it, I'm forced to work with the parameters I'm given.

So I for the code, I need to have multiple methods and I'm trying to make/take variables from the first method, modify it in a second method, and then use that modified variable in a third separate method. But I'm not sure I understand what method types I need or if I need to use ref, out, whatever.

The code that I'm posting here (two methods that will eventually pull the variables into a third method) as of right now doesn't throw out any errors yet, but I don't think will work for what I need.

I'm trying to take `ascore`, `midScore`, and `finalscore`, `tryparse` it in the first method, then modify it after its been *tryparsed* in the first method, and then use that final *tryparsed*/modified variable for my third method calculation. I was told that I would need to use a bool for the first method and a void for the second as well. So I can't figure out how to get my final ascore, midScore and finalscore variables to be tryparsed and modified from the first two methods for my third method.

```
    private bool DoGrades(out decimal ascore, out decimal midScore, out decimal finalscore)
    {

        if (decimal.TryParse(assignmentBox.Text, out ascore) && (ascore <= 100) && (ascore >= 0))
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(midtermBox.Text, out midScore) && (midScore <= 100) && (midScore >= 0))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(finalBox.Text, out finalscore) && (finalscore < 100) && (finalscore >= 0))
                {
                    IsTrue = true;
                    return IsTrue;
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Input must be between 0 and 100");
                    assignmentBox.Text = "";
                    midtermBox.Text = "";
                    finalBox.Text = "";
                    finalBox.Focus();
                    IsTrue = false;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be between 0 and 100");
                assignmentBox.Text = "";
                midtermBox.Text = "";
                finalBox.Text = "";
                midtermBox.Focus();
                IsTrue = false; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input must be between 0 and 100");
            assignmentBox.Text = "";
            midtermBox.Text = "";
            finalBox.Text = "";
            assignmentBox.Focus();
            IsTrue = false; 
        }
        DoGrades(out ascore, out midScore, out finalscore);

        return true;
    }

    private void BonusPoints (ref decimal itMajor, ref decimal lovingIt)
    {

        if (itMajorCheck.Checked)
        {
            itMajor = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            itMajor = 0;
        }

        if (lovingCheck.Checked)
        {
            lovingIt = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            lovingIt = 0;
        }

        ascore = ascore + itMajor + lovingIt;
        midScore = midScore + itMajor + lovingIt;
        finalscore = finalscore + itMajor + lovingIt;

    }
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. My guess is that you're misinterpreting the question.
2. I have no idea why you are calling `DoGrades` within `DoGrades`, that's just going to create an infinite recursive loop. `DoGrades` seems fine otherwise.
3. `BonusPoints` appears to be your major misinterpretation.  There is no point for `itMajor` and `lovingIt` to be `ref` variables, since any value coming in is not used and is always overwritten.  (Also I don't see why the bonus would be broken out into two variables, but whatever.)
4. I am guessing your teacher wants the third method that does the calculation to accept all the values by reference.  That's the only point it would actually serve a purpose, though passing the bonuses by `ref` is unnecessary.

### Code

```
void CaclulateScores() 
{
  decimal aScore;
  decimal midScore;
  decimal finalScore;
  decimal itBonus;
  decimal lovingBonus;

  if (DoGrades(out aScore, out midScore, out finaleScore)) 
  {
     BonusPoints(out itBonus, out lovingBonus);
     // I assume you this is what your last method signature is.
     ApplyBonus(ref aScore, ref midScore, ref finaleScore, itBonus, lovingBonus);
  }
}

void BonusPoints (out decimal itBonus, out decimal lovingBonus) 
{
  itBonus = (itMajorCheck.Checked) ? 10 : 0;
  lovingBonus = ((lovingCheck.Checked) ? 10 : 0;
}

void ApplyBonus(ref aScore, ref midScore, ref finaleScore, ref bonus, itBonus, lovingBonus)
{
  aScore += itBonus + lovingBonus;
  midScore += itBonus + lovingBonus;
  finaleScore += itBonus + lovingBonus;
}
```